# Replacing interior wall sconce in old house - how to mount

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I have an old house with black metal boxes on which there were old wall scones.  All of the boxes have a threaded nipple in them which held the previous sconces.  I am able to use a hickey to attach the new sconce via a threaded rod which works but there is nothing to counter rotation of the sconce around the thread.  I could probably screw in some small "anchor" screws to help secure it better but I was wondering if these old style boxes have any kind of mounting holes that a universal mounting plate might work with.  Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question and looking at this picture. I don't think so. You're probably better off doing as little as possible with the wiring in this house. **Be very careful**. The only thing that I see here that is younger than me (including the method of installation) are the yellow wire nuts and the black pigtail.

Comment: yeah, the wiring is old rubber coated wire, it's actually in good condition given its age.  I wrap each wire with new electrical tape as a "just in case."  Any idea what this type of box is called?  I can't even find a picture of one to get an idea of what might be buried behind the plaster.

Comment: I have seen them but I don't know the call out would be for them.

Comment: The old 3-1/2 inch metal boxes were usually used for lighting fixtures, this one has the hickey , I would look close as many of them did have threaded holes at the edge that may be covered by the plaster / concrete wall.

Comment: Could you an old work box there ?   Not sure if your wall is solid or not.